# php Sessions not work well without www

Tags: php, session

my sessions only work with a sub-domain, e.g. *www.* ,and do not work without that sub-domain.

For example, when a user is logged in.

If the address is not on the sub-domain. Typing does not logged in.

I set session *cookie_domain* but it did not work.

// I do not want to redirect by htaccess Because sub-domains Both have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this probem use this code

```
session_name("name");
ini_set ("session.cookie_domain", '.domain.com') ;
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.com');
session_start();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the php session to work all your subdomains, you must change `cookie_domain` option. Type this to top of your script:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com' );
```

Comment: Did you type this top of your script?

Comment: yes;
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.sooran.com' );
session_start();

Comment: Clear all cookies both subdomain and not-www versions. Then test it again. It must be work technically.

Comment: i add this file for clear all session But not worked;
http://www.sooran.com/clear.php

Comment: I test it with this order (sooran.com/clear.php, sooran.com/add.php, www.sooran.com/show.php) and it shows the session vars with value. It works.

Answer (score 1):

`www.domain.com` and `domain.com` are NOT the same website. They are the mirror copy of each other

For this reason, cookies set on `domain.com` will NOT be used on `www.domain.com` and vice-verse, because it would be unsafe to assume they are the same thing.

You can override this behavior to some extent by allowing the session cookie to work on all subdomains as well as the main domain by setting the php.ini setting `session.cookie_domain` to `.domain.com`