# PHP session not working between www and not-www

Tags: php, session

After a successful login, I set a PHP session. It works properly but the issue comes when the user goes from "www.example.com" to "example.com".

Looks like the session is not registered.

This is how I set the session:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = $username;
$_SESSION['email'] = 'email';
```

Is there anyway for make the session work in both URLs? Will be great avoid redirections.

EDIT:

I'm trying with this, without success.

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.domain.com' );
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.com');
session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = $username;
$_SESSION['email'] = 'email';
```

Comment: How are you setting your sessions? We need to see some code..

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21971329/6140684) out

Comment: As @AntonisTsimourtos has pointed to, domains despite having the same content, are not the same "physical" place. You need to adjust the cookie domain or redirect everyone to one or the other. Most websites redirect to one domain, so www or non-www.

Comment: @antonis-tsimourtos Damn, I didn't find that question. I will try, thanks!

Comment: I've added the code that I use for set the session.

Answer (score 0):

Set PHP INI option

[session.cookie_domain](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain)

e.g.

```
session.cookie_domain=.example.com
```

You must prefix it with `.` to ensure it works on all subdomains as well.

Comment: I stand by my answer.

Comment: @JimmyAdaro yes , that should work. Just make sure you're using the correct domain name.