# $_SESSION PHP doesn't work without www

Tags: php, session, isset

A strange problem with `$_SESSION` vars in `PHP` :

When I'm on www.mywebsite.com `$_SESSION` vars works and `if(isset($_SESSION[...]))` is `true`. But if I go to mywebsite.com (without www) : `if(isset($_SESSION[...]))` is `false` ! Why and how to resolve that ?

**My .htaccess :**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mywebsite\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/mywebsite\.com\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

If I make the resolve upside down in my htaccess (without www => with www) it works but why not I this way ?

Comment: Check your session cookie settings. http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find this post on here:

[php Sessions not work well without www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21930678/php-sessions-not-work-well-without-www)

Containing the following solution:

```
session_name("name");
ini_set ("session.cookie_domain", '.domain.com') ;
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.com');
session_start();
```